# Calculating delta of bias using derivative of sigmoid function results always in 0

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, sigmoid

I am making an ANN using python, and got to the part of doing backpropagation. I soon bumped into the problem of trying to calculate the delta value of the bias. This became a problem because I'm using the sigmoid function, whose derivative (`sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))`) happens to return 0 when the activation value is 1.
Am I missing something here? The problem with it returning always 0 is that delta will be also 0, so I will not be able to backpropagate the weights of the biases.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the sigmoid function should only return near 0 for very large values, like `x>5` or `x<-5`.

My calculator shows the derivative of the sigmoid function being `~0.1966` for an input of 1.

Without seeing the code, I can't name what the problem is for sure, but here are a few possible things to check:

- The sigmoid function may not be properly implemented
- There is integer division somewhere
- Numerical roundoff to zero

Comment: That makes sense, but what is actually happening is that my input is not 1, because I'm working with biases I set sigmoid to return 1. So then whenever I call the function it returns 1 if it's bias. And that ends up returning 0 calling its derivative

Comment: You set the sigmoid function to return 1? Then of course the derivative will return zero because 1 * (1 - 1) will always return zero. The sigmoid function should only return 1 when x approaches positive infinity. Why have you always set the sigmoid function to return 1?

Comment: Not always, only when working with the bias neuron, because it's whole gimmick it's supposed to be that it's activation value is 1.